# Measure WIND speed with GPIO.wait_for_edge (What to do when there is no speed)

Tags: gpio

I am measuring wind speed with a sample routine that use the duration it takes to receive 200 cycles on a GPIO pin.

The problem is, when I get in the measuring loop ...

```
NUM_CYCLES = 200
start = time.time()
for impulse_count in range (NUM_CYCLES): 
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(25,GPIO.FALLING)
duration = time.time() - start
```

if the wind stop, there is NO cycles anymore and the loop never finish

I used treading with a global variable thinking that within my loop I could see if a timer would resolve my issue.... the PI is still lock within the wait_for...

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the simple answer is don't use wait_for_edge.

Use callbacks instead.

A callback is a piece of code called asynchrously when an event happens, in this case a change in GPIO level.

RPi.GPIO uses add_event_detect to create a callback.

This is a [pigpio example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_read_RPM_py).  You should be able to do similar in RPi.GPIO.